# C#, parsing multiple numbers on the same line

Tags: c#, .net, file, parsing, format

If I got a line like this:

```
6 3 3 3 33 3 3 3 3 7 2 1 1 1 11 1 1 1 13 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 21 1 2 2
```

How would I parse this into a int array in C#? The thing is I don't have a determinate amount of numbers and specific amount of digits to parse.

Comment: string.Split on the space

Answer (score 7):

```
string numbersString = "6 3 3 3 33 3 3 3 3 7 2 1 1 1 11 1 1 1 13 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 21 1 2 2";
var numbers = numbersString.Split().Select(token => int.Parse(token)).ToArray();
```

That is assuming all your numbers fall into integer range.

**Update.** And of course that will only work if each string part represents a valid integer - otherwise `int.Parse` will fall.

Comment: +1: This would be my approach as well. Note to OP that if the string contain anything that cannot be converted to an int, this will blow up!

Comment: could you use TryParse so that it won't blow up? Or would that be a fundamentally bad idea?

Comment: @BrianJ, well, definitely you can, although it will take a little bit more of work. I can update post with a sample if you want me to.

Comment: You don't need to for me, but thank you for offering. I was mostly just asking from a design perspective if that would be a good approach to handle line that might not contain only integers.

Comment: @BrianJ, it mostly depends on the concrete situation. There might be cases where you might want to emit default value, say 0, skip the token, or throw the exception. So generally this might be a good idea to introduce `TryParse` here.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx):

```
string test = "A B C D E F G";
var array = test.Split(' ');
```

Comment: The OP asked for an int array, so you are only half way there :)

Answer (score 0):

Begin with digging up the String.Split API call, followed by type casting to convert strings to numbers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx is a good starting point.